# Why is python sklearn feature selection chi square (chi2) test not symmetric?

Tags: python, feature-selection, chi-squared

The chi2 function from the sklearn feature selection package returns the chi-square statistic and the p-value. It should be symmetric in the sense that the chi-square statistic is the same regardless of the order in which the variables are given, but it doesn't seem to be.

Here is a code example:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import sklearn.feature_selection as fs

#creating two correlated normal variables
n = 100
cov = [[1.0, 0.75], 
       [0.75, 1.0]]
x = np.random.multivariate_normal([0,0], cov, n)

x1 = x[:,0]
x2 = x[:,1]    

#turning them into discrete values (with the pandas quantile function)
#I am using two different number of categories for the two variables, 
#which makes the effect I am talking about much more pronounced
x1_q = pd.qcut(x1, q=5, labels=False)
x2_q = pd.qcut(x2, q=15, labels=False)

#need to turn one of them into a two dimensional array
#in order to use the chi2 function

x2_m = x2_q.reshape(n, 1)
chi2_1 = fs.chi2(y=x1_q, X=x2_m)

#now I reverse the order
x1_m = x1_q.reshape(n, 1)
chi2_2 = fs.chi2(y=x2_q, X = x1_m)
```

**My question:** 
why are chi2_1 and chi2_2 not the same? The example uses random numbers. But as an example  I get a chi-square statistic for chi2_1 of 89.59 and for chi2_2 of 37.92 in one of my runs. Any idea what I am missing here?

Comment: It seems that they are always different in 3 times. I assume that difference comes from the fact that you take 2 different datasets (even though built on the same rules) and also take different quantiles (`5` and `15`). I pretty sure, if you take the same quantile result will be comparable.

Comment: It looks like sklearn.feature_selection.chi2 does not compute chi-squared stats between each non-negative feature and class, but does just calculate the Pearson chi-squared test statistic for each feature column under the H0 that each category is equally likely.